# How to place text as subscript under mathematical operator in equation?

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

I would like to put some text in math mode below a mathematical operator (or a symbol), similar to `\substack` in `\sum`, as the red text below the `\max` operator in the following image

[image: example subscript]

How to do this?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You should place the expression in the subscript, as shown below. Most LaTeX [books](http://ctan.org/pkg/lshort) explain this. E.g.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \textbf{Display mode}:
        \[\max_{1 \leq i \leq N}\]
    \item \textbf{Inline mode}: version without \verb!\limits! would look like \(\max_{1 \leq i \leq N}\), version with \verb!\limits! would look like\(\max\limits_{1 \leq i \leq N}\) inside a text.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Note how `\limits` command force the subscript under operator in inline mode (if you think you need `\limits`, think again — maybe the defaults look better after all! cf. [this answer here on TeX.se](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32827/120984)).

If you find that the subscripted expression is too long and introduces excessive whitespace, you could use `\smashoperator` macro from the [`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package, as in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231813/adjustlimits-in-combination-with-smashoperator).

Comment: ah thanks, I thought it was limited to \sum command only. Silly me.

Answer (score 125):

Solved this for Inline mode by using `$\underset{1 \leq j \leq n}{\max}$`, however this approach requires the `amsmath` package.

Comment: This is particularly useful when using user defined operators. `$\operatorname{Res}\limits_{z=z_{0}}$` will not give you the desired result, whilst `$\underset_{z=z_{0}}{\operatorname{Res}}$` will.

Comment: This is also useful when you want to put a subscript under something LaTeX doesn't think is a math operator (like that's a meaningful distinction), and therefore prevents the use of \limits.

Comment: @AlfredoHernández I think [`\operatorname*` is the way to go](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics#Custom_operators) for `\limits`-compatible custom math operators.

Answer (score 16):

I would solve it like this:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}  
\[
    \max\limits_{1\leq j\leq n}
\]  
\end{document}
```

Comment: In display math, there's no need to use `\limits`.

Answer (score 5):

As someone suggest above. We should use `\underset` command:

```
\underset{1\leqslant j\leqslant n}{max}.

\underset{\substack{\rho\to 0\\ n\to\infty}}{l.i.m.}
```

(for my question above).

Comment: I try to format code in your answer, however it suggest strange solution with wrong typography. Also is not clear  what you mean with "(for my question above)." so I suggest to delete it.

Comment: I would not delete it, it works like a charm for me.

Comment: Thanks for the `\substack` suggestion, it allows multiple lines. I was using simply `\\ ` but it didn't work.