# Adjustlimits in combination with smashoperator

Tags: math-mode, mathtools

I would like to use the method `\adjustlimits` from the `mathtools` package in conjunction with the `\smashoperator` method. In the MWE I don't know how and where to use the `\adjustlimits` method. Trying to write it at the beginning with and without parentheses always produces errors.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
  \smashoperator{\sum_{i \in X \colon i \neq 5}} \, x_i  - \smashoperator{\sum_{i \in \bar{X} \colon i \neq 8}} \, y_i
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I believe you can't use `\adjustlimits` along with `\smashoperator`.

Comment: @egreg Is there any other trick to align the limits? It must be something to fake the height of the `X` in the first sum to be the same height as the `\bar{X}` in the second sum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\adjustlimits` operation requires the operators to be at the same brace level, which is not possible with `\smashoperator`. In this case you can easily adjust things manually:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
\smashoperator{\sum_{i \in X \colon i \neq 5\vphantom{\bar{X}}}} \, x_i  -
\smashoperator{\sum_{i \in \bar{X} \colon i \neq 8}} \, y_i
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\vphantom` with the highest object as argument will adjust the size.

However, the documentation of `mathtools` specifies that operators should *immediately* follow one another, in order for `\adjustlimits` to work, so this approach would not work anyway, because of the `x_i-` between the summation operators.

Here's how I would set this, with `\substack`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
\sum_{\substack{i \in X\vphantom{\bar{X}} \\ i \neq 5}} x_i  -
\sum_{\substack{i \in \bar{X} \\ i \neq 8}} y_i
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]