# how to write underneath max in formula latex

Tags: math-mode, equations

can someone one please help to write this formula in latex[image]

```
\begin{equation} 
\max\limits_{{P^{\circ}_t(j)}} E_{t}\sum_{s=0}^{\infty}\zeta^s M_{t,t+s}
\left[P^{\circ}_{t+s}(j)-\mathcal{MC}_{t+s}(j)\righ‌​t]Y_{t+s}(j) 
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 21):

I take it the main issue is the typesetting of the curly braces around the material immediately below "max". Just change

```
\max_{{P^{\circ}_t(j)}}
```

to

```
\max_{\{P^{\circ}_t(j)\}}
```

Remember that in order to typeset curly braces, you must type `\{` and `\}`, not just `{` and `}`.

No need for the `\limits` directive, by the way.

---

To fully reproduce the equation shown in the screenshot, you also need to provide `\mid t` items in two of the subscripts.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} 
\max_{\{P^{\circ}_t(j)\}} E_{t} \sum_{s=0}^{\infty} \zeta^s M_{t,t+s}
\left[ P^{\circ}_{t+s\mid t}(j) - \mathcal{MC}_{t+s}(j) \right] Y_{t+s\mid t}(j) 
\end{equation} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: My problem was that everything inside {} was going to the right of max. I do not want {}, so I have only single {} without \{\}. The solution was to include \limits

Comment: @Marcel - Were you using `\max` in inline math mode or in display math mode? In both the OP's use case and in my answer, `\max` is used in display math mode -- in which case it's not necessary to use `\limits`. If, in contrast, `\max` is used  inline math mode, then `\limits` is indeed needed if the objective is to place the argument *below* "max".

Comment: It was in cases environment inside align environment so I guess inline math mode?

Comment: @Marcel - Indeed, inside a `cases` environment `\textstyle`, aka inline math style, is in use.

Comment: [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13212/178369) shows how to use `\limits`