Mathematical formula: max
How to write the following using latex? Unfortunately, $\max_{\beta in \mathbb{N}^d}_{|beta| \leq k}$ doesn't appear like this, we want the terms under max to appear just like in the picture


Welcome. // Please add a short (about 10 lines of) code, which compiles, shows your problem and your approach.  Results in better answers, prevents a quick close of your question. Thank you

Could you provide more information? I.e. what code did you try, and what did it produced (that is, why do you say $\max_$ doesn't appear like this). If the question is just "how to put something under the max symbol", it is likely to be a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342538/how-to-write-underneath-max-in-formula-latex, if not, please elaborate so we can help you...

I am not even sure how to make the terms under \max to appear like this.

I suggest to use some guides/tutorials to learn LaTeX: What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?
%% Compile and read me!
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[\max_{\substack{\beta\in\mathbb{N}_0^d\\|\beta|\leq k}}\|\partial^\beta f\|_{L^\infty}\]
\end{document}



Extending Sebastiano's answer: Limits are placed besides the operator in text mode and above/below in display mode. If switching to display mode is not an option, use \limits:
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
    Text mode: $\max_{\substack{\beta\in\mathbb{N}_0^d\\|\beta|\leq k}}\|\partial^\beta f\|_{L^\infty}$.
    
    Text mode with \verb+\limits+: $\max\limits_{\substack{\beta\in\mathbb{N}_0^d\\|\beta|\leq k}}\|\partial^\beta f\|_{L^\infty}$.
    
    Display mode:
    \[
        \max_{\substack{\beta\in\mathbb{N}_0^d\\|\beta|\leq k}}\|\partial^\beta f\|_{L^\infty}
    \]
\end{document}


No one should ever use \limits in text mode math. It is better not to tell users about this as they do not understand when to use it and when not to.

@daleif I agree that in 99.9% of all cases, it's a bad idea because it breaks the line spacing. Honestly, I have never used \limits in my entire life. But I don't agree that people shouldn't be told about what exists.

It is the same reason why users should never be told that \\ can be used in the normal text. Some information should just not be given to normal users. Trust be we have spent years correcting users who used \\ in their text instead of making new paragraphs.

Thank you very much for the citation of my name :-). It is very nice see it.
