# How do I place a bit of text below another in an equation

Tags: equations

What I want to achieve is shown below:

[image]

Now from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13209/how-to-add-text-under-symbol-in-equation) question, I tried to put in `\argmin_{C}` to test if it works. However, this returns with an error. What am I supposed to do here? I must mention that what I am trying to achieve is not a subscript.

Comment: Which error? `\argmin` is probably not defined by default

Comment: that makes sense! So how would I approach this problem? @ChristianHupfer

Comment: `\usepackage{amsmath}` and `\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}` with `\argmin_{C}` in display style, most likely

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Let me try that!

Comment: Also, you should use `\DeclareMathOperator{\dist}{dist}` (without star) if you don't want `dist` to look like the product of the four variables `d,i,s,t`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}
\DeclareMathOperator{\dist}{\mathit{dist}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\argmin_{c_i\in C}\dist(c_i,x)^2
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Though your answer shows the correct code, you might like to improve it by adding some explanatory text, about what the code does / how ist works ;-)

Comment: How would you induce space between *Ci* and *C*, and also *arg min* and *dist(.)* ?