# Complex Mathematical equation?

Tags: mathematics

How do I write the below mathematical equations? I am Newbie to this Latex world. please help me

[image]

Comment: This site normally frowns on "do it for me" requests.  Is there a particular aspect of this that you're struggling with?  Otherwise, I'd recommend one of the many intros to LaTeX.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you (a) load the `mathtools` package, (b) define macros called `\argmin` (as a "math operator") and `\norm` (as a "paired delimiter), and (c) use the `\substack` macro (which is provided by the `amsmath` package, which is loaded automatically by the `mathtools` package) to typeset the material below `\argmin` more compactly.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{argmin}
\begin{document}
\[
R^*=\argmin_{\substack{RR^t=I,\\ \det(R)=1}}
    \sum_{i=1}^n \omega_i \norm{RX_i-Y_i}^2_2,
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

For the equation of R* this can be a useable LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
R^*=\underset{RR^t=I,\det(R)=1}{\operatorname{argmin}}\sum_{i=1}^n|RX_i-Y_i\|^2_2,
\]
\end{document}
```

This will yield:

[image]

I partially composed the code for this equation by using the app [Mathpix](https://mathpix.com/). Then I edited it.

`\operatername` will show `argmin` as upright (non-italic) and add an extra space between `argmin` and the following character. The arguments are still italic, except for `det` because of the use of `\det`.

The use of `\underset` will show the arguments under `argmin` instead as a subscript. For the summa symbol, the supscripts and superscripts are automatically added above and underneath the symbol.

Everything else is pretty straightforward.

You have to use the package `amsmath` to be able to use `\underset`. Have a look at:

[How to add text under symbol in equation ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13209/how-to-add-text-under-symbol-in-equation?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Do consider writing `\sum_{i=1}^n` instead of `\overset{n}{\underset{i =1}{\sum}`. (If MathPix produces the latter output, then that's an indictment of the quality of the code produced by MathPix.) Also, the curly braces in `{det}` do nothing at all except create code clutter. By writing `\det`, one gets upright lettering, which is appropriate for *math operators*; other examples of math operators in LaTeX are `\sin`, `\cos, `\lim`, and `\log` -- and many more. Finally, the expression `_{2'}` can't be right: the original formula contains a comma at the end, *not* a "prime" linked to "2".

Comment: Hi @Mico, Mathpix didn't write `\overset and` `\underset` for `\sum`, but I first edited this formula in inline mode and changed to display mode. In inline mode it showed superscripts and subscripts as usual, not on top and above. That's why I overlooked this. I made changes by removing non-functional curly braces. Mathpix did cause the use of a lot curly braces, but I like it to use as a startinpoint. I also overlooked that `det` was supposed to be upright. Also changed the comma at the end. Thanks, nice to learn from a pro. I think we helped @veeresh, to get on the way enough right now.