# Placing an identity directly beneath a symbol

Tags: spacing, typography

How do we we write in latex a phrase directly under another symbol.
I want to get the r going to infinity directly beneath the Tilda as shown below . However am unable to do so

[image]

I tried using \sim_{\r \rightarrow \infty} but this does not work.

Comment: Use \underset. Try!

Comment: Related: [How to add text under symbol in equation ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13209/5764)

Answer (score 0):

Just using `\underset{below}{upper}`...and I think that you can compile yourself the final code.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[F_{ij}\underset{r\to\infty}{\sim}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k_j}}\]
\end{document}
```