# Bmatrix: how to make subscript exactly underneath \max or \min?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, subscripts

```
$$\begin{Bmatrix}
     \max_{\left(x\right)}
\end{Bmatrix}$$
```

[image]

Is it possible to move the subscript directly under `\max` instead of slightly to the right of it?

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13209/how-to-place-text-as-subscript-under-mathematical-operator-in-equation.

Comment: `\max\limits_{\left(x\right)}`

Comment: Do you really need `Bmatrix`? Anyway, you don't need `\left(x\right)`, but just `(x)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A natural way would be:

```
\[\begin{Bmatrix}
    \displaystyle\max_{\left(x\right)}
  \end{Bmatrix}\]
```